# onclick registering for multiple buttons with the same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now when I click on a separate button that uses the class "btn-danger" it will get removed. How can I modify my functions to only remove anything when its related to the function being ran?

```
function UpdateTrash(wo)
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions/markTrash.php",
        data: 'wo='+wo,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
            //alert("Record successfully updated");
        }
    });
}

$("#dataTables-example").on('click', '.btn-danger', function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

$("#dataTables-example2").on('click', '.btn-danger', function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Button:

```
<td><br><center><button type="button" name="trashButton1" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="UpdateTrash(<?php echo $orow['WorkOrder']; ?>);"/>Trash</button></a></center></td>
```

Other button:

```
<td><center>
<button type="button" name="rush1" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger" onClick="UpdateRush(<?php echo $orow['WorkOrder']; ?>);"/>Rush</button>
</center><br><center>
<button type="button" name="pool1" class="btn btn-outline btn-info" onClick="UpdatePool(<?php echo $orow['WorkOrder']; ?>);"/>RFP</button></a>
</center></td>
```

Comment: The problem description is not very clear.  Can you create a JsFiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the issue is in your jQuery selector.

`$(this)` -> `<button></button>`

`.parent()` -> `<div></div>`

Here is a working example. https://jsfiddle.net/gcLt9d8f/

HTML:

```
<div id="dataTables-example">
<button class='btn-danger'>
Button 1
</button>
</div>

<div id="dataTables-example2">
<button class='btn-danger'>
Button 2
</button>
</div>
```

JS (jQuery):

```
$("#dataTables-example").on('click', '.btn-danger', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});

$("#dataTables-example2").on('click', '.btn-danger', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```